# Reset the former ViewController presented

Tags: objective-c

i've embed my first ViewController in an navigation controller. This auto generate an back button to all the ViewControllers.

The problem is that when i save a video into my core data it automatic go to a new ViewController, but then i'm able to go back to the ViewController where i added the video. Is there a way to like delete/reset the former ViewController that has presented and therefor control how far you can go back by clicking the back button?

Or what would be the best solution?

Comment: Could you please provide some code which yo are using to save the video and try to transit to viewcontroller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to offer advice without seeing your exact use case, but it sounds as though instead of pushing a viewController onto a navigation stack, you might want to do something like present a modal viewController.

Instead of doing `pushViewController:animated`, try `[self presentViewController:newViewController animated:YES completion:nil]`. If you're presenting your viewController via a segue in Interface Builder, change the segue type to 'modal'.

You'll also then need to add a button to dismiss your viewController - you can use the `[self dismissViewController:animated:completion]` method.